# Java List and Collection ordering inquiry

Tags: java, list, collections

I know a List in java is guaranteed to maintain an order, but a Collection is not.

My question is, if I have a list1, and I assign that list1 to a collection, and then I cast that collection to a List list2, will list2 have the same order as list1?

Or can it lose the order since it was at some point habdled as a collection?

Thank you all for your help.

Comment: Casting references back and forth doesn't interact with the underlying object.

Comment: Why don't you try it and see? :)

Comment: A `List` *is* a `Collection`. Assigning the *reference* to the `List` object to a variable of a super type will not change the *object* itself, just the type seen by the *compiler*.

Answer (score 4):

You are mixing up two concepts:

1. The compile time declaration of a variable, field, ...
2. The runtime "identity" of an object

In other words; of course, the compiler lets you write:

```
List<Whatever> stuff = new ArrayList<>();
stuff.add(whatever);

Collection<Whatever> stuffInCollection = stuff;
Object loosingAllTypeInformation =  stuffInCollection;
List<Whatever> castingBack = (List<Whatever>) loosingAllTypeInformation;
```

But at runtime, none of these assignments have any effect on the **list object** in memory. It still sits there, it is still an ArrayList object; and it has one member of type Whatever.

In other words: creating multiple variables/fields that reference the same object doesn't have **any** (direct) effect on the referenced object; no matter what kind of object that is.

The only thing that might change when having multiple variables/field reference the same object might be the point in time when that object is eligible to be garbage collected.

Comment: You don't need to cast. Actually, you *shouldn't* cast, since that bypasses compiler type-checking.

Comment: I updated the answer; to give a "valid" usage of that cast (as his question is actually mentioning casts).

Answer (score 2):

Order will be the unchanged, because you always handled references to the initial List which does not change anything in the List instance.

It is different if you add the List to a Set. This would, dependent on the Set you use, change the order.

Answer (score 1):

Changing reference type doesn't affect object.